# save dropbox thumbnail to disk fails generating stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropbox-api

I'm currently getting thumbnails from dropbox using the core api. I'm able to convert the thumbnail byte[] to a base64 dring and have my browser render it.
But when I try to convert the same byte[] into a memorystream and save it to disk, it fails with Invalid parameter.

```
public void WriteImageToFile(byte[] Inbyte, String FileName)
    {           
        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Inbyte))
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        } 
    }
```

where inbyte is the bytes from dropbox.

I've seek different posts about changing the position of the stream to 0 "rewind" but no luck so far.

Anybody else had this issue?

Comment: So the line that's raising an exception is the `Image.FromStream(ms)` line? Have you done some sanity checks like verifying that `Inbyte` is of the length you expect? If you just write `Inbyte` to a file, can you then open it?

Comment: Hi @smarx Embarrassing :) I only had the Path of the MetaData for the directory with the content and didn't point to the actual item inside. So now everything works just fine.

Comment: I'm glad things are working. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, it was the path to the content directory and not the content inside I was pointing to :)